# How to Close Wizard after Print Report in Odoo 10

Tags: python, odoo-10, wizard, rml

I customized a print check button which will pop up a wizard form in Payment Menu in order for user to choose the check print out data will be a cash check or not.

In my wizard print button i return code as below

```
@api.multi
def action_print(self):
    return self.env['report'].get_action(self.payment_id, 'xxx.xxx_report')
```

After report showed, the wizard still remain unclosed. I've searched on odoo forum and stackoverflow regarding this topic, there're a lot of posts but no definite answer. So i decided to re-post here.

How to close wizard form after print report?

Comment: Uhmm I think you can only return one action. So, or you return the report to download it or you return the action to come back and close the wizard.

Comment: Hi @ChesuCR thanks for your comment, but expected result is when click the button system will return report for user to download and as well as close the wizard form. I understand on Odoo function is to return 1 action only. Therefore i'm asking if there are any work around solution.

Comment: Maybe you can make some workaround with JavaScript. But I think it is not worth to save only one single click.

Comment: any idea how? @ChesuCR